# Select best model with lasso

Tags: r, bioinformatics, glmnet, lasso

I try to select the best model with the glmnet package and lasso. I have got a huge gene matrix with over 54.000 rows called *testmatrix*. And I have some predictors. I tried the following code for only one row of the matrix *testmatrix* and it worked. I found the best coefficients for my model. But now I want to find the best model for the whole testmatrix. 
Here's my code:

```
library("glmnet")

# Predictors
pred <- cbind(gene1, gene2, gene3, gene4, gene5,.... gene20)


# test_matrix as matrix
testmatrix <- as.matrix(test_matrix)


# Fit
fit.lasso <- glmnet(pred, testmatrix[1,], alpha = 1)
plot(fit.lasso, xvar= "lambda", label = TRUE)

#Model selection
cv.lasso <- cv.glmnet(pred, testmatrix[1,])
plot(cv.lasso)


#Coefficient extraction
coefficients <- coef(cv.lasso)
```

That's the outcome:

```
26 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                      1
(Intercept)    9.6293874346
gene1          -0.0082932332
gene2          -0.0660038076
gene3           .           
gene4          -0.0493033328
gene5           .           
.....           .
gene20         -0.0730450238
```

The non-zero coefficients are selected for the best model for the first row of the testmatrix. But I don't want to have 54.000 best models, I want only one.
But how can I find the best model for all 54.000 rows of the matrix? The outcome should be like above.

How can I get it?